# jQuery disabling a function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On my website I use Bootstrap and have a navigation menu with a dropdown.

Now I added some JS code to have the dropdown menu open on hover.

```
    <!-- MouseOver on menu -->
        $(function() {
            $("li.dropdown").hover(
                function(){ $(this).addClass('open') },
                function(){ $(this).removeClass('open') }
            );
        });

    },
```

I also use [enquire](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) to only have this hover effect active when on the desktop.

```
<!-- Activate javascript based on mediaquery -->
$(document).ready(function() {
    enquire.register("screen and (min-width:40em)", {

        // If supplied, triggered when a media query matches.
        match : function() {
        <!-- MouseOver on menu -->
            $(function() {
                $("li.dropdown").hover(
                    function(){ $(this).addClass('open') },
                    function(){ $(this).removeClass('open') }
                );
            });

        },

        // If supplied, triggered when the media query transitions from a matched state to an unmatched state.
        unmatch : function() {
            <!-- MouseOver on menu -->
            $(function() {
                $("li.dropdown").unbind("hover");
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Now the enquire.js part is working perfectly. So when the user is on a desktop the .hover attribute is given to the function. And when he is at a  a mobile device, the lower section gets executed. However, how do I take this .hover attribute away again?

I'm trying to unbind or unset the function, but this doesn't seem to work.

```
            $(function() {
                $("li.dropdown").unbind("hover");
            });
```

Maybe this is a basic question, but I'm not good at jQuery and I'm kinda stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/hover and you need to unbind a specific way:

```
$("li.dropdown").off( "mouseenter mouseleave" );
```

also I could be wrong on your specific instance but you can probably just use straight CSS for this instead of JavaScript/Enquire.

sidenote: I don't think you need the extra `$(function(){ ... })` wrappers in match/unmatch as you are already executing this inside the `.ready` method.

Comment: You are correct, the extra function() wrapper is indeed not needed.

Comment: Also you answer is working perfectly. Thank you so much!
CSS might be possible to use, but I rather do a small hack on the main Bootstrap functionality (which uses jQuery) instead of writing the enter dropdown from scratch in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the .on and .off JQuery functions:

Here is an example of how that works:

To attach an event:

```
$('#myDiv').on(
 {
   mouseenter: function()
   {
      $(this).css('background-color','blue');
   },
    mouseleave: function()
   {
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
   }});
```

To remove the event again:

```
 $('#myDiv').off(' mouseentermouseleave');
```

Here is a JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/loanburger/sv5wLrkq/

So in your case you would do this:

```
$("li.dropdown").on(
 {
   mouseenter: function()
   {
    // your code
   },
    mouseleave: function()
   {
  // your code
   }});
```

Then to remove the event listener:

```
$('#li.dropdown').off(' mouseenter mouseleave');
```

Comment: Apparently only the last line was enough to make it work. Thank you for helping.